# Formal Define of "Structure" in Generating Function with Practical Example

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

**Problem**

> Let $C_n$ be the number of ways to color a set of $n$-labelled balls
>   using **red, white and green** where an **even number of balls are to
>   be colored red** and an **odd number of balls are to be colored
>   green**. Construct **EGF** for a formula of $C_n$

$\\$

**My Understanding**

I superficially understand that we use **EGF** with so called **"structures"** when we are asked to find for each $n$ the number of ways to arrange the elements of an n-element set into such a structure given. (However still I don't know how the structure mathematically formalized.)

We have

$$F(x) = \sum_n^\infty f(n){x^n\over n!}$$
where $f(n)$ is **the number of structures** on an n-element. Thus may be in given problem, there are two or three structures depending on how we define the concept of structure.

**Question**

I had searched bunch of example sturctues like following:

```
(1) The trivial structure of “set”: $F(x) = e^x$ .
(2) The trivial “1-element set” structure: $F(x) = x$.
(3) The trivial “empty set” structure: $F(x) = 1$.
(4) The trivial “non-empty set” structure: $F(x) = e^x − 1$.
(5) The trivial “even-size set” structure: $F(x) = \cosh(x) = (e x + e −x )/2.$
(6) The trivial “odd-size set” structure: $F(x) = sinh(x) = (e x − e −x )/2.$
```

With well-mathematically formulated structure, I think we can do addition or multiply to yield comprised version of **EGF**. However, still, to do addition or product, we first need to reveal a disjointness between what we want to add and multiply. Back to the problem, the bold-faced three structure - 1) colored in one of red/white/green 2) even number of reded 3) odd number of greened - looks not **disjoint** obviously.

Anyone can provide me any proper suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

> **Hint:** You might want to take a look at chapter 2: *Labelled structures and exponential Generating functions* of *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf)* by P. Flajolet and R. Sedgewick.

This is a great presentation of admissible structures and their corresponding EGFs,  mathematically formalized which might please you.